# How to loop through array and find if key

Tags: javascript

So basically I want o loop through an error (what i already did) and print the other key

```
var planet = "sun";
var planets = [{
    type: "sun",
    desc: "sun"
}, {
    type: "moon",
    desc: "moon"
}];

var pln = planets.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < pln; i++) {
    console.log(planets[i]);
}
```

How can i I find out if the var planet is in the array planets and print out the description from that key if so?

Comment: So, here you want to find the object that has the `type` of `"sun"`, and print out the other object's `type` (`"moon"`)?

Comment: FYI - neither the `sun` nor the `moon` are planets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare `planet` with current `planets[i].type`. Once planet is found in array remember to terminate loop using `break` keyword:

```
var pln = planets.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < pln; i++) {
    if (planets[i].type === planet) {
        console.log(planets[i].desc);       
        break;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use filter

```
var planet = "sun";
var planets = [{
        type: "sun",
        desc: "sun"
        }, {
        type: "moon",
        desc: "moon"}];

var planetObj = planets.filter(function(obj){ 
 return obj.type==planet;
})[0].desc;//sun
```

If you are unsure if planet exists, you may wish to see if the array returned from filter actually contained any elements, or perhaps iterate the returned set if there were more than one you were searching for.

Comment: It can be just return `obj.type == planet`, `if` is not needed.

Comment: @dfsq - Yes, not sure why I wrote it as if(){}.

Comment: That's going to cause an error if the planet in not in the array. You need to check that the filter returned something before trying to access its `desc` property.

Comment: @blex - Yes, but the OP states that they already know the element is there. This is just showing concept, I am not going to write a whole framework as an answer :) Please see edit indicating the need for error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think this is what you want:

```
var pln = planets.length;
for (var i = 0; i < pln; i++) {
      if (planets[i].type == planet) {
          console.log(planets[i].desc);
          break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: What's the point of simply copying the code of another answer? You forgot to copy what `pln` is defined as so your code doesn't even work.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I'll add that. Of course, it leads to the problem that `planets` is still not defined and still wouldn't work. At some point, one would hope that the user would actually read the code and infer what is going on.

Comment: How does this answer differ from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28843035/215042) which was clearly posted earlier and is an exact copy (except the comparison === v.s. ==)? What value does this answer add? *"Please provide a reason for the downvote"* > I'd be surprised if it *didn't* get downvoted if I were you...?

Comment: I posted mine seconds after the answer mentioned. I added his `break;` because I thought it was a good idea, but I didn't need to add it. The `pln` was requested by @Nit. Not sure what I did wrong? Should I have removed my answer once I saw the answer mentioned? Thanks for helping me become a better member :)

Comment: Furthermore, I think that you and @Nit overlooked that my loop is the same as the OP, thus the only thing I really contributed was the if statement.

Comment: Let me quote the hover text on the down-vote button: _"This answer is not useful."_ Since it doesn't offer anything over other, already existing answers, it is not useful.

Comment: I didn't copy anyone's code. Should I have removed my answer when I found out that someone had answered something so similar? I'm asking to know how to be better in the future.

Comment: I didn't realize, from your original comment, that you were accusing me of plagiarism or I would have made a bigger deal about it. I completely came up with that if statement and feel like I was wrongly downvoted. I'd like to know how to handle this better next time.